# How to make a discord bot which deletes messages with attachments if the author doesn't have certain roles

Tags: python, discord

Basically as in the question. I want to create a bot which will delete a message with an attachment if the author of the message does not have either the bot or trusted role within my server.

Currently i have this:

```
 **if message.attachments:
       if not "*roleID*" or "roleID" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
           await client.delete_message(message)
           await client.send_message(message.channel, "Sorry mate only trusted members or bots can attach things to prevent spam")**
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your full code, this snippet seems close to achieving what you want to do, it's just the second `if` condition that is malformed and causing problems.

Assuming you replace `*roleID*` and `roleID` with the respective bot and trusted role IDs, `*roleID*` will always return `True` regardless of what you put into the string, because it is not empty. Whatever is right from the `or` is pretty much disregarded at this point and the `if` statement will always return `True`, deleting any message that passes through this piece of code.

Another thing to note is that you should use the list comprehension you've made for both `roleID` checks instead of just one, so you'll have to save that into a variable.

Try to see if the following works:

```
if len(message.attachments) > 0:
    author_roles = [role.id for role in message.author.roles]
    # replace both botRoleId and trustedRoleID with the respective IDs (as strings, because role.id is a string as well)
    if "botRoleID" not in author_roles or "trustedRoleID" not in author_roles:
        await client.delete_message(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Sorry mate only trusted members or bots can attach things to prevent spam")
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: Thank you. It works as far as deleting the images but it looks like the role validation isn't working. But it's better than what i had so thanks for the help :)